# Using Python's replace() method to implement stopword functionality

Tags: python

I am trying to strip substrings out of each element in a list of strings. I am having trouble figuring out how to handle the case of a string having multiple substrings (stopwords) that I want to remove.

```
wines = ("2008 Chardonnay", "Cabernet Sauvignon 2009", "Bordeaux 2005 Cotes du Rhone")
stop_words = ("2005", "2008", "2009", "Cotes du Rhone")
result = []

for wine in wines:
    for stop in stop_words:
        if stop in wine:
            x = wine.replace(stop, "")
            result.append(x)

print result
```

Changing the if statement to a for or a while returns garbage or hangs. Any advice?

Comment: you may want to use `x.strip()` for example on each string to remove whitespace

Comment: @jamylak I am doing just that elsewhere in my script and punctuation as well, this is just a small piece of a larger project.

Comment: I don't think "substrings" is the correct term. One could refer to it specifically as a  "tuple of strings" or more generally as a "sequence" of strings, but not as a "string of substrings"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little indentation and changing variables around would solve your problem

```
for wine in wines:
    glass=wine #Lets pour your wine in a glass
    for stop in stop_words:
        if stop in glass: #Is stop in your glass? 
            #Replace stop in glass and pour it in the glass again
            glass = glass.replace(stop, "") 
    result.append(glass) #Finally pour the content from your glass to result


result
[' Chardonnay', 'Cabernet Sauvignon ', 'Bordeaux  ']
```

If you want to be adventurous you can use regex. I believe in this case, regex might be faster then simple looping

```
>>> for wine in wines:
    result.append(re.sub('('+'|'.join(stop_words)+')','',wine))    

>>> result
[' Chardonnay', 'Cabernet Sauvignon ', 'Bordeaux  ']
>>>
```

Or make it as a list comprehension

```
>>> [re.sub('('+'|'.join(stop_words)+')','',wine) for wine in wines]
[' Chardonnay', 'Cabernet Sauvignon ', 'Bordeaux  ']
>>>
```

Comment: @jamylak: I think you are just next to me peeping onto my laptop :-)

Comment: Haha thanks guys, I went with the first post :) I like the regex implementation better as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
wines = ("2008 Chardonnay", "Cabernet Sauvignon 2009", "Bordeaux 2005 Cotes du Rhone")
stop_words = ("2005", "2008", "2009", "Cotes du Rhone")
result = []

for wine in wines:
    x = wine
    for stop in stop_words:        
        x = x.replace(stop, "")
    result.append(x)

print result
```

Using `regex` would be a lot better IMO

```
>>> wines = ("2008 Chardonnay", "Cabernet Sauvignon 2009", "Bordeaux 2005 Cotes du Rhone")
>>> stop_words = ("2005", "2008", "2009", "Cotes du Rhone")
>>> import re
>>> [re.sub('|'.join(stop_words),'',wine) for wine in wines]
[' Chardonnay', 'Cabernet Sauvignon ', 'Bordeaux  ']
```

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner, taking into account jamylaks's suggestion of using `strip()`:

```
[reduce(lambda x,y: x.replace(y, "").strip(), stop_words, wine) for wine in wines]
```

Be aware that this works fine in Python 2.x, but not in Python 3, as `reduce()` was moved to a separate library. If you're using Python 3, do this:

```
import functools as ft
[ft.reduce(lambda x,y: x.replace(y, "").strip(), stop_words, wine) for wine in wines]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that everybody warns against using reduce and it is not available as a builtin in python3

Comment: This is one of the cases where using a `reduce()` is appropriate, I'm gonna miss it in Python 3...